# Allow screen sharing current tab in Chrome using Azure Communication Services (ACS)

Tags: google-chrome, screensharing, azure-communication-services

I'm writing an Angular web app for VoIP communication that includes screen sharing using Azure Communication Services.

When screen sharing is initiated in **Microsoft Edge**, the pop-up for selecting screen/window/tab includes the current tab with the call itself. **Google Chrome** on the other hand does not offer current tab in the pop-up menu (it offers other opened tabs). I can only screen share the whole chrome window.

I've read that Google Chrome can record or share stream from browser using getDisplayMedia() and selfBrowserSurface can be set to the value 'include' to include the current tab in the pop up menu.

Problem is, that I don't know how to use this method in combination with Azure Communication Services and it is not recommended to use in combination with ACS. ACS Best Practices Documentation clearly states

> Your application shouldn't use native browser APIs like getUserMedia or getDisplayMedia to acquire streams outside of the SDK.

Is there any way to force Google Chrome to allow screen sharing current tab?

**Or even better solution**: Is there any way to programmatically select current tab without displaying Pop-Up Window at all? (I can see the security concern in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is rolling out the change to hide the current tab (unless selfBrowserSurface is set to 'include') along with the reordering of tabs. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1407021#c7 for details.

For 1.10.0-beta.1 version of the sdk, a local run of calling sample app
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial

shows the existing tab as an option:
[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJDv.png)

on this version of chrome:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKtyM.png)